# Why I cant access findOneAndUpdate in Mongoose using a plugin override?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to override the findOneAndUpdate method using a plugin by doing this:

```
// Messages is a Mongoose Model
await Messages.newFindOneAndUpdate(query, payload, options);
```

In the Message schema definition I have:

```
MessagesSchema.plugin(require('../util/schema-api-aware-plugin'));
```

And that plugin just declares the static method *newFindOneAndUpdate*:

```
module.exports = (schema) => {

    schema.statics.newFindOneAndUpdate = async (query, data, options) => {
        const me = this;

        try {
            return await me.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, options);
        }
        catch (err) {
            errorManager(err, res);
            return null;
        }
    }

};
```

When I run that, I get a type error `me.findOneAndUpdate is not a function`. The model works, the plugin is attached as it should, the static method is present but for some reason, *me* which is supposed to be *this*  does not have the method *findOneAndUpdate*, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use arrow functions.

Mongoose extensions (like plugins and instance methods) depend on Mongoose being able to set `this`, which is not supported for arrow functions.

The [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) states:

> Do *not* declare methods using ES6 arrow functions (`=>`). Arrow functions explicitly prevent binding `this`, so your method will not have access to the document and the above examples will *not* work.

Comment: I always forget about this is not supported in arrow function! jeez... Thanks!